# UICollectionview in UIStackView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uistackview

I have a `tableview` and would want to add views dynamically to it, based on the data. For every other view it is easy. Works like charm but `collectionview`, I don't even see the view on `stackview`.

The `UICollectionView's` `cellForItem` delegate is not called, the `numberOfItems` delegate is called but not `cellForItem`.

Not sure if I am missing anything.

```
  func testView() -> UIView {
    let containerView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    containerView.backgroundColor = .red

    let layout = KTCenterFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0
    layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 80, height: 100)
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 30, 20, 30)
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout).then {
        $0.dataSource = self
        $0.isScrollEnabled = false
        $0.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: false)
        $0.register(NPSCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "npsCell")
        $0.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width-100, height: 500.0)
        containerView.addSubview($0)
    }
    collectionView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        make.height.equalTo(500).priority(500)
    }
    return containerView
}
```

I am adding this above view in `CellForRowAtIndexPath` in

```
     cell?.stackView.addArrangedSubview(testView())
```

Any pointers?

Edit: here is the screenshot
I just see a blank space
[image: screenshot]

Here is my `StackTableViewCell`

```
       lazy var stackView : UIStackView! = {
    let stack = UIStackView()
    stack.axis = .vertical
    stack.distribution = .fillProportionally
    stack.alignment = .center
    stack.spacing = 10.0
    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stack.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority.required, for: .vertical)
    return stack
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    contentView.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(10)
        make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(20)
        make.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-20)
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-10)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem that the cell wasn't displaying and I just gave it a size manually using a property of the collectionView try this approach